# retrieve key based on value in dictionary nested inside another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am attempting to retrieve a key based on the value of a key:value pair of a dictionary in a dictionary. The following is an example of the setup I have:

```
dictionary = {
    1 : {'foo':'bar', 'boo':'car', 'moo':'jar'},
    2 : {'a':'x', 'b':'y', 'c':'z'},
    3 : {'do': 're', 'me': 'fa', 'so': 'la'}
}
```

In the real code, the 'main' key is also a number. For example, if my input was 'y', I want to return the integer 2.

I attempted to use

```
keyList = list(dictionary.keys())
valueList = list(dictionary.values())

position = valueList.index('y')

result = keyList[position]
return result
```

The above code would work if the values were not dictionaries.  How could I go about extracting this information from the dictionary of dictionaries? Would it be easier to use something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach could be along these lines:

```
def find_top_key_by_nested_value(dct, value):
    for k, d in dct.items():
        if value in d.values():
            return k

>>> find_top_key_by_nested_value(dictionary, "y")
2
```

Answer (score 2):

Invert the dictionary using nested [dictionary comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) like so, and use the inverted dictionary to look up the keys:

```
dictionary = {
    1 : {'foo':'bar', 'boo':'car', 'moo':'jar'},
    2 : {'a':'x', 'b':'y', 'c':'z'},
    3 : {'do': 're', 'me': 'fa', 'so': 'la', 'foobar':'z'}
}
inverted_dictionary = {v2: k1 for k1, v1 in dictionary.items() for k2, v2 in v1.items()}
print(inverted_dictionary)
# {'bar': 1, 'car': 1, 'jar': 1, 'x': 2, 'y': 2, 'z': 2, 're': 3, 'fa': 3, 'la': 3}
print(inverted_dictionary['y'])
# 2
# For duplicate values, the **last** key is returned:
print(inverted_dictionary['z'])
# 3
```

This method is fast and avoids scanning the contents of `dictionary` multiple times during repeated lookups. It reduces the contents of `dictionary` to just what you need for the lookup.

Note that if a value occurs more than once, the **last** key will be stored and returned.

Comment: What happens if there end up being duplicate keys? I assume they'll just be overwritten?

Comment: @JRiggles Yes, the keys for dup values will be overwritten. Thank you for your comment! Updated the answer to show what happens for duplicate values.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want

```
dictionary = {
    1 : {'foo':'bar', 'boo':'car', 'moo':'jar'},
    2 : {'a':'x', 'b':'y', 'c':'z'},
    3 : {'do': 're', 'me': 'fa', 'so': 'la'}
}


def find_key(value):
    for d in dictionary:
        if value in dictionary[d].values():
            return d


print(find_key('y'))
# => 2
```

It will return the key number of the first dictionary that contains the instance of `value`